# Bot is bit confused to capture the user's intention

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, bots, outlook-restapi

I have enabled email channel in azure and deployed bot in azure.

the bot is bit confused to capture the users intention

For example:- If user sent a mail to bot like

[image: please click here to view Sample image]

The bot needs to capture "what can you do" and need to send a reply but bot is capturing
"HI Bot.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nWhat can you do\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks and regards,\r\n\r\nKrishna."

IF user sends

[image: please click here to view Sample image]

The bot needs to capture "hi" and need to reply with specific responce
but the bot is capturing "hi\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks and regards,\r\n\r\nKrishna.".

is there any way to understand the users intention?

if user mails only greeting the bot has to welcome the user with welcome message. if user mails a question with greetings the bot has to capture specific users intention.

Because every user has different standard signatures and formats in their mails.
please suggest me the best approach.

Comment: Typically, based on the words the bot can identity one intent based on the text and slot values for the intent. I don't think it can capable of capturing certain are of text. I might be wrong, but would love to see if you get a solution

Comment: Bot Framework SDK/ABS don't have anything that could parse greeting/signatures directly. You could try searching through [MS Graph API or Outlook APIs directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0). However upon a precursory glance, it doesn't look like they over such API either. If you look at their [Message element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/message-ex15websvcsotherref) there doesn't seem to be something for field of greeting/signature either.

Comment: That being said, signs seem to point to having to implement custom logic to parse through to the body that you want.

I'm not quite sure what "UniqueBody" is in Outlook, but maybe you could dig into that, and see if that leads you anywhere (beyond my knowledge, as I specialize more in Bot Framework rather than Outlook)